# UDP broadcast send from PHP and receive in C#

Tags: c#, php, udp, broadcast, lan

I'm trying to send a broadcast UDP message to a C# application. I have tried the following code to send the message. Which I found on the php.net website as [a comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php) to the [socket_sendto manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php).

```
<?php 
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1); 
socket_sendto($sock, $broadcast_string, strlen($broadcast_string), 0, '255.255.255.255', $port); 
?>
```

This doesn't work for me, maybe it's my network.

But it does work if I replace the broadcast IP `'255.255.255.255'` to my specific IP e.g. `'192.168.1.128'`. I can see this message coming in with Wireshark, while I can't see this using the above code. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the PHP side of the code. I really want to use broadcasting or some kind of multicasting for my program, so I'm a bit stuck at the moment ;)

I use the following on the (C#) receiving end (for testing):

```
UdpClient subscriber = new UdpClient(15000);

IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15000); ;

byte[] pdata = subscriber.Receive(ref ep);
string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pdata);
MessageBox.Show(data);
subscriber.Close();
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: works here. What's the return value of `socket_sendto` ?

Comment: Fixed it allready. I guess I can't send an UDP package to the `255.255.255.255` range while the ip addres of the php server is in a LAN range e.g. `192.168.1.*` with a subnetmask of `255.255.255.0`. To work around this, I sent the package to the `192.169.1.255` range. Answers explaining as to why this actually is the case are still welcome though ;)

Comment: @Artefacto tried again just for kicks... The returnvalue sending to `255.255.255.255` is a positive integer even though the UPD packet doesn't reach my client computer.

Comment: Notice that I made a typo in one of the messages above. The range obviously has to be `192.168.1.255` instead of the `192.169` one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the `MSG_DONTROUTE` flag in your script. Taking inspiration from this [CodeGuru post](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-286258.html), if this isn't specified the routers make the decision on whether or not to broadcast your message.

```
socket_sendto($sock, $broadcast_string, strlen($broadcast_string), MSG_DONTROUTE, '255.255.255.255', $port);
```

Comment: As I have read the [post on CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-286258.html) I would have to say this is the solution to my original problem. Thanks! For now the [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650719/udp-broadcast-send-from-php-and-recieve-in-c#comment-7860084) is still in place, so I haven't tested this yet.

Answer (score 1):

255.255.255.255 is a "limited" broadcast whereas your 192.168.1.255 is a "directed" broadcast.
Limited in simple terms means that it is only send within the LAN. LAN as defined by directly connected hosts, i.e. with no router in between. Routers--with a few exceptions--do not pass a limited broadcast but a directed broadcast.

Now, with your initial problem and question, I can only guess that you are sending your broadcast across a router.